# Javascript append to variable

Tags: javascript

```
        var gen = "            scrollwheel: true,\n"+
              "            streetViewControl: true,\n";

    if (val == "FALSE"){
                gen = "            control: false,\n";
                } else {
                gen = "            control: true,\n";
    }
gen = "            zoom: true,\n";
```

What would be the best way to append the `gen` variable so that everything gets added one after the other.

Comment: So many things look wrong is so little code... Why are you comparing to the string `FALSE` and not the boolean `false`? Why are you creating what is essentially an object with strings? What happened to the indentation?

Comment: @Donald why are you using strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`+=` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) as a convenient way to append strings:

```
var gen = "            scrollwheel: true,\n"+
          "            streetViewControl: true,\n";

if (val == "FALSE"){
     gen += "            control: false,\n";
} else {
     gen += "            control: true,\n";
}
gen += "            zoom: true,\n";
```

<sup>Note: `gen += "foo"` is equivalent to `get = gen + "foo"`.</sup>
But in this case, I think the conditional operator (`?:`) is simpler:

```
var gen = "            scrollwheel: true,\n"+
          "            streetViewControl: true,\n" +
          "            control: " + (val == "FALSE" ? "false" : "true") + ",\n" +
          "            zoom: true,\n";
```

Or if the intent is to create a JSON string, just create the object directly:

```
var gen = {
    scrollwheel: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    control: val != "FALSE",
    zoom: true
};
```

And then turn it into a string using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).